# Microsoft Groups/Teams: Can't create plans for Planner App

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams, microsoft-planner

I created a Group using 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-groups?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

and then used 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-put-teams?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

to create a Team. Now I am facing issue when adding a plan using a Planner app

```
"Failed to create the plan."
```

How I can fix this issue?

[image]

In my investigations, I found that the other team members are able to create plans. As an owner of the team, I am not able to create them. if I am trying graph API I'm getting an error:

**You do not have the required permissions to access this item, or the item may not exist.**

Comment: Could you please check if you are listed as [Member](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) as well?  If not, try adding and see if that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fixed after adding the creator of teams as a member too. So I had to add the user who is creating Teams in Team members too.

Answer (score 1):

I'm glad you came right and that I was able to help. I'm updating the answer so that it's more clear on a few points:

1. Technically, this actually has nothing to do with Teams at all, it relates to Office 365 Groups, which forms the core underneath Teams, Planner, and more. You actually link in your question to the Groups docs, incidentally. I've updated the question title to reflect this.
2. I haven't tested this exactly, but I doubt that it needs *your* account exactly in the Owners and Members - I suspect the main constraint is that there needs to be at least **one** person in **each** of those roles (that means there has to be at least one Owner and at least one Member). Arguably, this is actually a bug in Planner, but it was maybe never detected by Microsoft because if you create a Group from the web interface, it automatically puts your user in as Owner and Member.
3. If you do put your own account into both positions, but that's not what you want long term, you could probably just take them out after creating the Planner plan.
4. Just a reminder that best practice is to have more than one owner of a Group, in case/when the original Owner is not/no longer available.

Comment: Yes, the owner is already added. but still it does not allow to create plans.

Comment: Try put someone as a member as well (even if it's the same person as the owner), and see if it works. I had a similar problem a few years ago and I think that helped - there had to be people in the groups.

Comment: Oh, another thing, are you using Delegated or Application permissions?

Answer (score 0):

I made sure that there was another owner on the Team, demoted and removed the owner and the re-added them to the team.  This resolved the issue that I had with multiple teams